# Edit a question to add comments to the code?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39091/help-me-pick-a-good-name-for-a-class), an edit to the code <s>(by other than the asker)</s> added this block of comments to the code:

```
    // duplication
    //     ||
    //    \||/
    //     \/
    try {
        listener = (SomeListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SomeListener");
    }
```

This appears to be an answer or comment, of sorts.

Is this good practice?  Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit history at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/39091/revisions shows that that edit was made by the OP.

Also IMO it's OK to edit question text to clarify the question (if you're sure of your clarification): similarly therefore IMO it's OK to add **comments** (not code) to the code, if (again) you're sure of your clarification, and if you think that clarification is necessary/helpful to help other people to understand the question.

Comment: I missed that it was the OP who made the edit.  I didn't read the history close enough.  Oops!

Comment: Similarly, if you're sure that an edit is wrong, you can use edit history to "Roll back" the edit to a previous version (explaining why you did so in an edit comment). If doing so results in an "edit war" then you might/must flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @ChrisW: Community♦ will also raise an autoflag in these instances.